# How do I get the arguments passed to a function that is a property of an object?

Tags: javascript, function

I have an object that has a property which is a function:

Example:

```
const obj = {func: function() {console.log('I am a function in an object')}};
```

When I call this function, I would call it by `obj.func()`. If I wanted to pass more arguments to this function, how can I access them? I've tried:

```
const obj = {
  func: function() {
    const args = [...arguments];
    console.log(args);
  }
}
```

so when I call `obj.func(arg1, arg2)`, I expect it to log what `arg1` and `arg2` is but this call returns the `obj` as the single argument. I have not found any other answer about this. BTW, I'm new  to javascript.

Comment: It's returning as array, not object...how do you want the output, could you give your params example and expected output

Comment: Declare parameters in the function definition, then use those? Or do you need varargs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An even easier option that does not need the `arguments` variable would be the following:

```js
const obj = {
  func: (...args) => {
    console.log(args);
  }
};

obj.func("value1", "value2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just paste it as a value...

```js
const obj = {
  func: function() {
    const args = [...arguments];
    console.log(args);
  }
}


obj.func("value1","value2")
```

or like this

```js
const obj = {
  func: function(arg1,arg2) {
    const args = [arg1,arg2];
    console.log(args);
  }
}


obj.func("value1","value2")
```

```js
const obj = {
  func: function() {
    const args = [arguments[0],arguments[1]];
    console.log(args);
  }
}


obj.func("value1","value2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop and `arguments` to straight away access your function arguments. Here's an alteration to your function:

```js
const obj = {
  func: function() {
    for (var iteration=0; iteration<arguments.length; iteration++) 
      console.log(arguments[iteration]);
  }
}
```